# DJANGO: how to change language site based on user's location?

Tags: python, django

anyone can help me , please !!!?
setting.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

# supported languages 
LANGUAGES = (
('en', 'English'),
('ko', 'Korean'),

)
```

Answer (score 4):

Django works it out on its own already, there isn't anything extra you need to do.

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)

> LocaleMiddleware tries to determine the user’s language preference by following this algorithm:
>
> - First, it looks for the language prefix in the requested URL. This is only performed when you are using the i18n_patterns function in your root URLconf. See Internationalization: in URL patterns for more information about the language prefix and how to internationalize URL patterns.
> - Failing that, it looks for the LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY key in the current user’s session.
> - Failing that, it looks for a cookie.
> - The name of the cookie used is set by the LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME setting. (The default name is django_language.)
> - Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header. This header is sent by your browser and tells the server which language(s) you prefer, in order by priority. Django tries each language in the header until it finds one with available translations.
> - Failing that, it uses the global LANGUAGE_CODE setting.

Comment: perhaps you've misunderstood !! I want my site automatically change language according to user's location !

Comment: @jacklucky - Perhaps you've misunderstood. Django *does* this automatically.

Comment: You can check the request`s ip address and assign the language session key with middleware, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Håken Lid how can i check the request's ip address, Does django support for that!!!?? please help me!

Comment: If you are using nginx or similar in front of django, make sure that the original ip is passed along with each request.

Answer (score 1):

@Sayse's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35126688/21945) is correct, however, Django does not automatically enable `LocaleMiddleware` for your project.

Once enabled (add it to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py) Django will perform language detection as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), and apps such as the admin app will use the appropriate translations.

But you still need to set up everything else; you have to mark up your translatable strings in your code and/or templates, set up the message files for each language, consider whether you want internationalisation support for URLs etc.

It would be a good idea to read the [translation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.utils.translation).